# library not found for -lFlurry_6.0.0 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I have earlier created an 32 bit app in Xcode. Now I updated XCode to 6.1 iOS 8.1. Additionally I used Flurry SDK 4.2.3 API earlier, now I downloaded flurry sdk 6.0.0 compatible with xcode 6.1.

But, now after importing this SDK into Xcode project the below error is displayed.

```
library not found for -lFlurry_6.0.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

libflurry library is already there in:

```
project>>general>>libraries section
```

What should I do to resolve it ?

Comment: Check your library search path, it might be pointing to old Flurry API only.

Comment: So,I should delete the whole line written in library search path??What should I write in library search path for the new flurry sdk???

Comment: Just give the latest path where your .a file and .h files relies.

Comment: After giving path to latest flurry sdk in library search path,following errors and warning displayed...      ld: warning: directory not found for option '-
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LiPhone'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LSDK'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-LviPhone'
ld: library not found for -lFlurry_6.0.0
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: As per the error stats, issue seems to me in your library search paths only